# Customizing name of "Help" buffer opening by package-menu-describe-package

Tags: buffers, package-repositories, help-mode

Hitting `RET` with point on a package name in the `*Packages*` buffer opens a help buffer, named "Help", describing the package. `RET` here invokes `package-menu-describe-package` which in turn calls `describe-package` which uses `with-help-buffer` to create this window. How can I customize the name of this buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `describe-package` uses `with-help-window` (function/macro `with-help-buffer` does not exist).

And `describe-package` explicitly intends to show buffer `*Help*` in the help window, not another buffer. It purposely wants to replaces any current contents of buffer `*Help*`.

You should not try to make it use another buffer.  If you really want to do that, then define your own command (e.g., based on the code of `describe-package`), and use that instead.  You can, for example, remap the keys that are bound to `describe-package` to your command.

Alternatively, if all you want to do is change the name of the help buffer after it is created and shown, then just do that.  Use command (function) `rename-buffer` - interactively or in Lisp code.

I bind `rename-buffer` to `C-M-S-f1`, and I use it quite often - in particular, to keep a `*Help*` buffer so that some help command does not overwrite its contents.

Comment: +1. I have `display-buffer-alist` customized to open all `*Help*` buffers in a particular frame and switch focus to it. However, I don't want to do this for a `*Help*` buffer spawned by `describe-package`. Changing the name would have been easy to handle with `display-buffer-alist`. I guess I should look at `defadvice`ing `describe-package`?

Comment: Why not just remap its keys to your own (similar) command? If you need to use something more than remapping (e.g., because of a particular keymap), consider `substitute-key-definition`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, although it's not really officially supported, by using "[advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html)".

It turns out to be very simple in this case. The function we need to advise `help-buffer`, and we just need to make it use a different buffer name.

If you just want a different name for that buffer, for example, if you want it to be called `*Package Info*` instead of `*Help*`, this is pretty simple. You only need the advice on `help-buffer` to exist when `describe-package` is running, and you can hardcode the

```lisp
;; Same interface as 'help-buffer: no parameters,
;; create the buffer if it doesn't exist yet,
;; and return the name of the buffer instead of
;; the buffer itself:
(defun package-help-buffer ()
    (buffer-name (get-buffer-create "*Package Info*")))

;; How can we make advice only apply while a
;; function is running? More advice! We advise
;; 'describe-package to advise 'help-buffer to
;; be overriden by our buffer getter function:
(advice-add 'describe-package :around
    (lambda (describe-package &rest arguments)
        (unwind-protect
            (progn
                (advice-add 'help-buffer :override 'package-help-buffer)
                (apply describe-package arguments))
            (advice-remove 'help-buffer 'package-help-buffer))))
```

If you want something more complex, this becomes a case of [my "How do I make separate Help buffers for each help topic?" question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80450/separate-help-buffers-for-each-topic). For example, in my setup, the help buffer for package undo-tree gets named `*Help (package: undo-tree)*`. You can look at [my answer on that question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80450/separate-help-buffers-for-each-topic/80451#80451) for how to do that - it includes `describe-package` as one of the examples.